# About Vi and Vim editor

Tags: unix, vim, text-editor, vi

What is the difference between vi and vim editor?? I want difference in technical point of view not in theatrical. If you gave example then it is much helpful for me or all the readers.

Answer (score 5):

From the vim documentation:

> Vim is a text editor that is upwards compatible to Vi. ... There are a lot of enhancements above Vi: multi level undo, multi windows and buffers, syntax highlighting, command line editing, filename completion, on-line help, visual selection, etc.. See
>   ":help vi_diff.txt" for a summary of the differences between Vim and Vi.

The `vi_diff` help page is quite extensive; it's over 1000 lines as of vim version 7.4. That's the best place to look. You can access it in vim by running `:h vi_diff`, or online at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vi_diff.html.

You should also be aware that on many systems running `vi` will actually invoke `vim`, because of the presence of either a hardlink or a symlink (or maybe even a script or executable, which I've seen). But there are slight differences between the two methods of invocation; for instance, running `vi` may not load your `.vimrc`.

Comment: You might want to help the OP by providing the links.

Answer (score 0):

vim has vi's features plus other features like, the ability to *visually* select blocks of code, and much more.  Syntax coloring/highlighting as well. You can use vim for just about anything you would use vi.

Answer (score -1):

Vim stands for Vi IMproved. It has been ported to multiple different platforms, but is functionally almost the same. Wikipedia it!